# Android 12 Splash Screen causing crash in <12 versions of Android with AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, android-splashscreen

I set the theme of the app to the one I created that inherits from `Theme.SplashScreen`, which is declared in `values-v31`. Now when I launch my app on devices running 11 and below, I get a crash. How do you customize the splash screen for 12 devices when your main app theme is `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar`?

This is the stack trace for <12 devices.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.app/com.my.app.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at com.my.app.databinding.ActivityMyBinding.inflate(ActivityMyBinding.java:66)
    at com.my.app.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.kt:55)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:243)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:213)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:148)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:76)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewUtilsLollipop.setStateListAnimatorFromAttrs(ViewUtilsLollipop.java:46)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout.<init>(AppBarLayout.java:215)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout.<init>(AppBarLayout.java:199)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at com.my.app.databinding.ActivityMyBinding.inflate(ActivityMyBinding.java:66) 
    at com.my.app.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.kt:55) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Post the entire stack trace.  Particularly for this type of crash, its always the bottom one that's the real problem-  the top ones are higher layers in the chain rewrapping it.

Comment: Can you upload you dependencies list and entire stack trace as @GabeSechan mentioned

Comment: "The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant)."  Tht's what's wrong.  Change your app's theme to be a Theme.AppCompat descendent (it may work if you just change the activity theme).  If necessary, make a Theme.SplashScreen for lower level apps so it will pick that up.  You can probably just steal the code for Theme.SplashScreen from the material library, that part is unlikely to actually be version specific.

Comment: Are calling `installSplashScreen()` before setting layout content of your activity? Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreen.Companion#(android.app.Activity).installSplashScreen()